# how to remove placeholder value when a date is selected in a jquery calendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, placeholder

I have a jquery calendar, with an icon, which on click fills the textbox with the selected value. However there is already a text in placeholder "please select a date" which is not getting removed and thus the date selected and the text "please select a date overlap each other". How to remove the value in placeholder when date has been selected?

My code is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" placeholder="Please select a date" data-constraints="@Required"  value="" ></asp:TextBox>
<span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
```

The Jquery script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage:'images/cal_icon.png'
        });
    });
</script>
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AXvO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a **.change** event to check if there is any input in the field:

```
    $("[id$=txtDate]").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "Please select a date");
        }
        else{
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code ,but it isnt working .I also used  $(this).removeAttr('placeholder'); but it isnt working

Comment: The selector would `$("#txtDate")`
Normal behavior for the placeholder is, once you set a value to the input the placeholder value is not shown anymore.